# How to reach every single element which is not list in random nested list?

Tags: python, nested, nested-lists

Assume there are a list like following, it is important to note that this is an arbitrary list, to demonstrate that list contains completely random lists with strings/numeric values:

```
[[["1"],"1"],["2",[["123",[[["23"]]],23],[12.3,"23"]]],[["5"],"1","1"]]
```

I want to get every single item in this list but I want to get only numbers or strings but not list. Let's say, I created a function which takes only strings, integers and float but not lists. I want to use this function.

I want to create the same list but with different object based on the function's output. Let's say function converts string to numeric value. I want to create a list like that:

```
[[[1],1],[2,[[123,[[[23]]],23],[12.3,23]]],[[5],1,1]]
```

I thought and I could not come with an answer. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: @DeepSpace No, that question only deals with lists within lists, not of arbitrary depth.

Comment: @DeepSpace And it explicitly does NOT want to flatten it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to traverse your entire structure recursively, and either store the results or call your function on the results right there.  It would look something like this:

```
sample = [[["1"],"1"],["2",[["123",[[["23"]]],23],[12.3,"23"]]],[["5"],"1","1"]]
def traverse(l, f):
    result = []
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            result.append(traverse(item))
        else:
            result.append(f(item))
    return result
```

Comment: Thans for your reply,
But when I use this, I end up with different list, if i use a function "float()"
[1.2, 1.0, 2.0, 12.3, 23.0, 23.0, 12.3, 23.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0]

Comment: if you change extend to append and if ı use my function inside of else: result.append(myfunction(item)),,,  this solution also works

Comment: I see, I didn't realize you wanted your output to remain in the same structure as the original.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that resembles a very simple attempt at nested [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
def map_nested(fnc, l):
    try: 
        return fnc(l)
    except:
        return [map_nested(fnc, sub) for sub in l]

>>> l = [[["1"],"1"],["2",[["123",[[["23"]]],23],[12.3,"23"]]],[["5"],"1","1"]]
>>> map_nested(float, l)
[[[1.0], 1.0], [2.0, [[123.0, [[[23.0]]], 23.0], [12.3, 23.0]]], [[5.0], 1.0, 1.0]]
```

It will apply the provided function `fnc` to all items in `l` that are valid arguments to that function (or to `l` itself) and attempts to iterate over the others.